# Do the effects of Burdenless armor and Heavyload Belt stack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

Both of them say they increase the carrying capacity of the character: [300%](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/ant-haul) for the [Heavyload Belt](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/belt-heavyload) and [Burdenless](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/magic-armor-and-shield-special-abilities/burdenless) by 50%.

I have a feeling they won't stack due to both using percentages, but there is no info on the Internet I can find.

Comment: [Related] [Multiplying and dividing](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/83188) • [Related, from D&D 3.5e] [Carrying Capacity and multipliers](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/36414)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They do stack. Absent any rule that says otherwise (and Pathfinder *is* absent of rules that say otherwise), the math works exactly like normal math: Ant Hauls' 3× carrying capacity and Burdenless armor's 50% increase (which is the same as 1.5×) just straight multiply together to give 4.5× carrying capacity.

The only alteration of multiplication rules in Pathfinder is for *modifiers* to *rolls*, which use [special rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Multiplying) (*PFRPG Core Rulebook*, p. 12) to keep roll modifiers from being multiplied into the stratosphere. Carrying capacity isn't a roll bonus or penalty, so multipliers to it behave as-written, in normal mathy ways.

Comment: Multipliers typically don't multiply each other still, they usually bump together (for 3.5x carrying capacity in this example)

Comment: @Delioth As explained in the answer, that's only for multipliers of roll modifiers. It's a common belief that it applies to other things, but it's mistaken.

Comment: Can you cite where it says things stack multiplicatively? If not, it's arbitrary and fully up to DM's call.

Comment: @Delioth The answer already does. It's not a call at all. “Hmm, the game doesn't tell me to change the fundamental laws of math, in fact the only place it mentions handling multipliers in a custom way, it explicitly says it applies only to roll modifiers… But I'm not sure then. Maybe I'm supposed to anyway?” ← This should not be happening.

Comment: The source you linked refers to a page on the d20pfsrd which is _not_ backed up in RAW (the glossary is entirely d20pfsrd-made)

Comment: @Delioth To the contrary, it's in the book verbatim. I don't have my book with me now or I'd give a page number, but if you have the PDF searching for "multiplier" will hit the page.

Comment: Back to the book now; it's Core, page 12. Thanks for prompting me to improve the post that little bit!