# Food and adventuring gear for creatures of unusual sizes

Tags: pathfinder-1e, equipment, creature-size, food-and-drink

Currently preparing a Pathfinder campaign, and the party has a Large monstrous humanoid and a Tiny fey (created races). As a part of the campaign will be set far from civilization, everyone will need adventuring gear.

The thing is : most of it is designed for Medium creatures, a part of it doesn't even exist for Small creatures, and there is absolutely nothing for Large or Tiny characters.

Three types of gear are a problem in our case : food, tents/sleeping bags and saddles.

- The [create food and water](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/create-food-and-water/) spell says that a horse eats three times as much as a human, but no general rule seems to exist about food needs for creatures larger than Medium or smaller than Small (assuming that Small and Medium creatures have the same food needs).
- Tents are designed to house a certain number of Medium creatures and there is no indication of how many creatures of other sizes can fit.
- Saddles seem to be designed for horses and are too heavy for Medium mounts.

Are there rules that exist to fix the problems of food needs, tents and saddles for creatures other than Medium ?

Comment: C.O.U.S.'s? I don't think they exist.

Comment: Is there even a point in answering? Poster is no longer here...

Comment: @JPChapleau yes, other searchers might come up with this site and also I'd like to know...

Answer (score 10):

The text on the Tents is specific about this.

> Tents come in a variety of sizes and accommodate between one and 10 people. Two Small creatures count as a Medium creature, and one Large creature counts as two Medium creatures. Packing up a tent takes half as long as assembling it.

There is no specific rule for feeding creatures of exotic size, however this information can be extrapolated from the tent description and other rules such as the ones for trail ration and other food items that mention that the version designed for Small-Sized humanoids weights only 1/4 as the original, which should translate to 1/4 of the content. This also matches the text on enlarge eprson that says that 1 size category increase is "double height and quadruple weight".

For other effects related to size, there's a lot of effects that mention how to handle this, for example, the text on [Feather Fall](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/feather-fall/) says:

> The spell affects one or more Medium or smaller creatures (including gear and carried objects up to each creature’s maximum load) or objects, or the equivalent in larger creatures: a Large creature or object counts as two Medium creatures or objects, a Huge creature or object counts as four Medium creatures or objects, and so forth.

By this, tiny creatures would count as 1/4th the size of a medium one.

There's several other examples that use this "rule" for handling creatures of unusual size so it can help as a "hard and fast" one in case nothing better is specified.

As for feeding animals, you can use the "Feed" entry in Animals & Animal Gear of the equipment. The cost depends on the diet of the creature, but here's an example:

> Consisting of various kinds of raw meat that have been jerked, smoked, or salted for preservation, a day’s worth of carnivore feed is adequate food for any Small or Medium meat-eating animal such as a tiger, bear, or dog. Larger carnivores might require up to 2 to 4 days’ worth of carnivore feed per day.

Finally, for the saddles, every creature that is not a "standard" riding animal like a Horse or Pony should use Exotic Saddles, which have a fixed prize.

Comment: Exotic saddles weigh even more than standard saddles and don't exist in smaller versions. Should I conclude that my halfling cavalier has to ride bareback ?

Comment: By RAW, the exotic riding saddle should weight 30 pounds and cost 30GP no matter what, and can be made for ANY creature. Of course, you may consider reducing the weight in your game. If you are riding somehting like a War Pony, then you can use normal saddles even if you're a Halfling.

Comment: @FlashRebel You could adjust weight by assuming that it grows/drops cubically. For example, if creature A is 2 times bigger in all three dimensions than creature B, it weights 2^3=8 times more, and vice versa. Keep in mind that large creatures spend less energy on heating because their surface is smaller, so if a bigger creature eats two times more, it doesn't automatically mean that it's exactly two times bigger *per se*. BTW, conversely, if you know weight difference, you could calculate size of similarly built creatures.

Answer (score 6):

To my knowledge there are no general rules for unusually sized gear. For that gear needing such information, my tendency is to take normal items and extrapolate their new weights and costs using the table [Armor for Unusual Creatures](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/armor/#TOC-Armor-for-Unusual-Creatures). This produces reasonable and predictable results with a minimum of hassle.

Note that if an item (like a [tent](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/goods-and-services/hunting-camping-survival-gear/#TOC-Tent)) already provides a capacity measured by size category, the item's capacity is half as many creatures of each size category bigger than what's given and twice as many creatures of each size category littler than what's given. [You even use normal math](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/84096/8610) to determine capacity.

Comment: I'd also note that for things like tents that double or halve, these multipliers don't work like normal pathfinder math (x2 twice normally gives x3), they work like conventional math (x2 twice gives x4, x2 thrice gives x8, 1/2 twice gives 1/4, etc.)

Comment: @Delioth [This answer sums that situation nicely.](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/84096/8610) Since that's the standard rule, need it really be mentioned again?

Comment: Ah, right. I remember having to poke and prod to get a proper source for that (since dice rolls are so prevalent and there's a different standard for dice modifiers vs. everything else); Since we've got a nice answer for it, I'd consider linking it at least- like I said, some (myself included) get stuck on the dice-modifier multiplication and forget that that isn't the only precedent.