# D&D 3.5 A party of 10lv can defeat Tarrasque

Tags: dnd-3.5e, encounters

I'm dungeon master and characters has awaken Tarrasque, team is like the following:

- barbarian, 10 level
- wizard, 10 level
- cleric, 10 level
- mage, 10 level
- fighter, 10 level
- ranger, 10 level

Mages don't have teleportation and they are not prepared (traps, support nearby) in any way.

There is chance they will survive this monster? They can fight and survive it ?

Note: party is in a wild area, like a desert, with no animals, no hiding and they can prepare 2 turns at max

Edit: it's a general question by choice, I wonder if is possible with any build to beat Tarrasque or not at 10th level

Comment: There is no way to possibly answer this. It depends entirely on what builds they've made and what kind of spells they've selected. I can't even tell for half the characters involved what kind of class they are, let alone what they're good at.

Comment: frankly speaking, with how dumb dnd 3.5e is with allowing you get skill checks and AC to insane levels, its quite possible for just the ranger to solo it, provided of course he has an optimized min/maxed build. Your going to need to provide a lot more information about the party before anyone can answer this.

Comment: @Theik English is probably not the OP's first language (location Italy), so they're working with translations. Mage and Warrior are most likely Wizard and Fighter in the original English.

Comment: @Carcer It could just as easily be a sorcerer though. Or a multiclass something/something. Right now, we don't really know anything except that level 10 characters are involved.

Comment: @Theik sure, and clarification would be helpful. I'm just pointing out there's probably a language barrier and so maybe moderate the tone a little.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]! It's entirely possible for a group of 6 level 10 PCs to defeat the tarrasque, but whether or not *your group* of 6 level 10 PCs can defeat the tarrasque is something else entirely! The site would need to see these PCs' character sheets or at least have a detailed description of each PC in order to provide answers that could help you. Thank you for participating and have fun!

Comment: Related: [One way to kill the tarrasque with 3rd-level PCs.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/21680/4563)

Comment: As a general question *Can these 6 generic level 10 PCs defeat the tarrasque?* absent binds except *The PCs only have 2 rounds to prepare* is too broad. That is, the answer's *Yes*, but *how* the PCs go about it is the *real* question, and answers'll depends on the degree of optimization allowed. The site needs to know *your* campaign's binds, gentlemen's agreement, house rules, and so on to answer this with something other than the path of least resistance, like an allip horde, Pun-pun, or a massive Diplomacy skill result.

Comment: Related: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dkb1/dnd/tarrasque.txt

Comment: @Dennisch There are slight differences between *3e* and *3.5* that make some of that out of date, but you may want to save that link for an answer if the question's reopened.

Answer (score 2):

The Average Party Level (APL) for your group is 11 (10+1 as they are 6). A Challenge Rating (CR) 14 encounter is described as "Epic" for them.

The [Tarrasque](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/tarrasque.htm) has a CR of 20.

The [d20 Encounter Calculator](http://www.d20srd.org/extras/d20encountercalculator/) litteraly calls it "Unbeatale". There might be a way but without preparation, I don't see how they can beat a monster with 6 attacks per rounds at +52/+57, an average DPR of 112.5, 858 HP with a 15/epic damage reduction and a *Regeneration* of 40 HP/turn. The description also add that it can only be slain with a *Miracle* or *Wish* spell, which your party can't have as they are level 9 spells.

Fortunately, it only has a speed of 4 squares, so most adventurers can run faster and, assuming the Tarrasque don't bother to run after such non-threats/small snacks for longer than a few rounds, can escape if they don't die first.

Comment: A scroll of *Wish* or *Miracle* costs 28,825 GP. That's not cheap but it's well within the reach of six tenth-level PCs, about 10% of their total wealth. Their wizard/cleric then has a 65% chance of making the caster level check to use the scroll successfully, or 88% for a Luck priest with a reroll to spend. So that obstacle is surmountable.

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent My initial reading of the question had the PCs in my mind's eye encountering the tarrasque *suddenly* (as in, "Eek! It's awake! What do we do?"). I'm currently DMing two campaigns of level 13 PCs—one group of 3 and one group of 5—, and *no one* in either group has a *wish* scroll gathering dust in case of a sudden attack of tarrasque! If the PCs are, like, going *tarrasque hunting* ("Is it tarrasque season?" "It's always tarrasque season"), then, sure, a *wish* scroll'll be a thing, but I don't think the the PCs' *typical* capabilities should be *overestimated.*

Comment: @HeyICanChan It'd certainly be highly unusual for a tenth-level party to have one (at that level, I'd probably be selling it to buy something more cost-effective), but OP did ask if there was *any* tenth-level build that can do it. I was commenting strictly on possibility, not probability.